# Trying to run a roll game on a discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord

So I am coding this discord bot and I want the bot to have a rolling game
When someone types in "jroll" the bot runs this:

```
var roll = (Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+1);
if (roll <=100){message.reply('Thats not enough, keep rolling')}
else{message.reply('Uuuuuh now those are some monies goy, you may get help')}
```

what I am trying to figure out is how to make a "jroll" run this rolling game
as you can tell I'm not that experiencied at js.

Comment: What is your question? Is not clear to me. You don't know how to create a bot in discord, or you don't know how to use javascript to create a *rolling game* at all? Your code sample reproduces some error?

Comment: Sorry if I made my self unclear.  I already have the bot the thing is I want it to run a dice like game. The bot tells the user to write jroll, then the bots use the code that I have made already. I dont know how to run the the var roll. That is all I want, when the user says jroll it runs the command

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @Paulo Costa, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example for you to start, keep rolling lol

(The idea is that you need a click event so everytime you click, you get a new roll and output the message based on the roll number)

```js
document.getElementById('rollnow').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var roll = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1);
  
  console.log('This roll is: ' + roll);
  
  if (roll <= 100) {
    //message.reply('Thats not enough, keep rolling')
    console.log('Thats not enough, keep rolling');
  } else {
    //message.reply('Uuuuuh now those are some monies goy, you may get help')
    console.log('Uuuuuh now those are some monies goy, you may get help');
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="rollnow">ROLL NOW</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question as you not understanding how to trigger your code from a specific message, if so, you could do something like this:

```
client.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.content == "jroll") {
        var roll = (Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+1);
        if (roll <= 100) {
            message.reply('Not enough, keep rolling');
        }
        else {
            message.reply('You win');
        }
    }
});
```